# Averaging through sql query and php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, loops

I am trying to average a couple rows in mysql with php mysql_query but I seem to be having some issues..

```
    $ratingsql = "SELECT AVG(Rating) AS RatingAverage FROM wp_reciperatings;";
    $ratingresult = mysql_query($ratingsql);
    // Print out result
    while($ratingrow = mysql_fetch_array($ratingresult)){
        echo "The average rating is ".$ratingrow['AVG(RatingAverage)'];
        echo "<br />";
```

My table looks like..

```
          ID           Rating
        _______________________
        |  1      |        1  |
        |  1      |        2  |
        |  1      |        5  |
```

The ratings go from 1-5, 5 being best. I am able to punch in that mysql query into my sql client and it works fine, how come it doesnt work on my page?

Also, how do I calculate the average of just ONE id?

Thanks a lot guys! Much appreciated.

Comment: Are you executing this in a wordpress plugin? Also, `where id = _number_here_` will give you the average for only one specific id

Comment: I have it executing in a page, this goes directly to a table inside my wordpress database.

Comment: Try changing `$ratingrow['AVG(rating)']` to `$ratingrow['RatingAverage']` in your code.

Comment: `mysql_query` is an obsolete interface and should not be used in new applications and will be removed in future versions of PHP. A modern replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/). If you're new to PHP, a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) can help explain best practices.

Comment: What sort of errors are you getting (if any)?

Comment: Hmmm... Maybe try putting `error_reporting(E_ALL);` and/or `ini_set('display_errors', '1');` at the top of your script to make sure you're seeing any important warnings/errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this -

```
echo "The average price of  is ".$ratingrow['AVG(rating)'];
```

to this -

```
echo "The average price of  is ".$ratingrow['RatingAverage '];
```

Since you're giving the result column an alias you need to use that alias in PHP to display the data.

The query for the average of one ID would be this -

```
SELECT AVG(Rating) AS RatingAverage 
FROM wp_reciperatings
WHERE ID = '1'; // replacing with ID as needed
```

Comment: I did see that mistake after i posted, I updated my code with the alias in the echo and it still wont display! I know I selected the right database and when I run it in my sql client it queries fine.

Comment: No errors at all and I added in

   if (!$ratingresult) {
    die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
    }

Comment: What ended up being the problem?

Comment: AVG(rating) -> RatingAverage